# popd before return / exit function

Tags: bash

In bash what is the proper way to `popd` before returning / exiting from a function?  For example,

```
function fn () {
    pushd ~ >/dev/null
    if [ $1 = $2 ]; then
        return 0;
    elif [ $2 = $3 ]; then
        return 1;
    else
        return 2;
    fi
    popd >/dev/null
}
```

Am I supposed to write `popd` before each return?  Or, should I be doing this another way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this I'd probably do it this way:

```
fn() {
    pushd ~ >/dev/null
    if [ "$1" = "$2" ]; then
        ret=0
    elif [ "$2" = "$3" ]; then
        ret=1
    else
        ret=2
    fi
    popd >/dev/null
    return $ret
}
```

that way I wouldn't have to repeat the "cleanup" code before each return.

An alternative would be to do the work in a subshell and have that `cd` to the desired directory, though that subshell could not modify the parent's environment (which is part of what we want after all).

```
fn() (
    cd ~
    if [ "$1" = "$2" ]; then
        return 0
    elif [ "$2" = "$3" ]; then
        return 1
    else
        return 2
    fi
)
```

Comment: Optional improvements include making `ret` local and checking the exit code of cd/pushd to avoid starting work in the wrong directory (in addition to the usual variable quoting).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this:

```
function fn () { 
    ( 
        pushd subdir >& /dev/null
        if [ $1 = $2 ]; then
            return 0;
        elif [ $2 = $3 ]; then
            return 1;
        else
            return 2;
        fi
    ) 
}
```

We create a subshell. When we exit this subshell, $PWD is restored.
So, if there is an error when errexit is enabled, it will restore $PWD automatically.

We could also set a trap:

```
trap 'popd' RETURN
```

However, you can set only one trap at a time for a signal. You can use a function to stack actions but this is overcomplicated for that usecase...